# Display a paged_table() in an HTML document

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I've got a function that, for some given data, outputs various tables and plots. I'd like to use this in an R notebook that gets knitted to HTML.

I rather like the way that tibbles and data frames are shown in knitted HTML documents by default:

[image]

However, this only works when a data frame/tibble is printed at the top level, not within a function call (unless the result gets returned and reaches the top level). So what can I do when I wish to output a data frame/tibble this way within a function? So far I've that

- using `print(mtcars)` produces the same plain-ASCII rendering you'd get on the R console;
- using `rmarkdown::paged_table(mtcars)` produces the nice-looking table above, but this isn't output (unless it happens to reach the top level); and
- using `print(rmarkdown::paged_table(mtcars))` again only produces the plain-ASCII rendering.

So what function is called to actually *output* the paged table? What do I need to to have e.g.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r}
do_things <- function() {

    rmarkdown::paged_table(mtcars)
    return(1)
    
}

do_things()
````

work as expected? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I've taken a look at `knitr::knit_print()` and `knitr::asis_output()` as well, both of which seemed like they might be useful. No combination of these worked; in particular, `knitr::knit_print(rmarkdown::paged_table(mtcars))`, which I naively expected might actually Do The Right Thing, does not print anything at all when invoked inside a function.

Comment: You may want to try a combination of `cat(rmarkdown::paged_table(mtcars))` and the knitr chunk option [`results = 'asis'`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/results-asis.html).

Comment: That doesn't work: `Error in cat(rmarkdown::paged_table(mtcars)) : argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `cat` with print method [`print.paged_df`](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/main/R/html_paged.R#L241),

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r}
#| results: asis

print_paged_df <- function(...) {
  cat(rmarkdown:::print.paged_df(rmarkdown::paged_table(...)))
}
  
do_things <- function() {
    print_paged_df(mtcars)
    return(1)
}

do_things()
```
````

Note the use of `:::` to access the `print.paged_df`, since it is an unexported function of `{rmarkdown}`

---

[image: paged table printed]

---

Comment: The `cat` doesn’t fit here — is it really necessary?! `print` should return the first argument.

Comment: I think yes `cat` is necessary because without it we would not get the returned table from `print.paged_df`

Comment: Bizarre! You’re right, but the method is completely wrong, it doesn’t implement `print` correctly at all!

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This works. For the record and for the benefit of anyone reading this at a later date, it appears you have to set `results = "asis"` as a chunk option on every chunk in which `print_paged_df` is called. (Explicitly or using `knitr::opts_chunk$set(results = "asis", ...)` or so.)

Comment: More precisely, you have to set this option on any chunk in which a function calling `print_paged_df` is called.

Comment: And, relatedly, setting `results = "asis"` also interferes with regular `print`-ing, so this is still not a wholly satisfactory solution; you can't just drop it into an existing notebook, use `print_paged_df` where appropriate, and expect everything to work.